# Fade in div before loading new content using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a parent div(class of container) and a child div inside it(class of home).

I want to fade out parent div before loading new child div inside it(class of about) using Jquery.

Here is the code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.container').on('click', '#about-btn', function() {
    $('div.container').fadeOut(1000);
    $('div.container').fadeIn(1000).load('ABOUT.html');
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}

.home,
.about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.bottom-nav {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="home">
      <button id="about-btn">About</button>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-nav">
    <h1>Bottom Nav</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**ABOUT.html**

```
<div class="about">
    <button id="home-btn">Home</button>
    <h1>ABOUT</h1>
</div>
```

How can I do this ?

Comment: If you are loading file, you have to use Promise.

Comment: @Wils Can you give some specific code ?

Comment: $.load(url,[data],[callback]);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wils for suggestion. Here is the solution using Ajax:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('div.container').on('click', '#about-btn', function() {
    $('div.home').fadeOut(500, function() {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "ABOUT.html",
        data: {},
        success: function(data) {
          $('div.container').hide().fadeIn(500).html(data);
        }
      });
    });

  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.layout {
  background-color: black;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  height: 70%;
  width: 100%;
}

.home,
.about {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: cyan;
}

.bottom-nav {
  height: 30%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: brown;
}
```

```html
<div class="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="home">
      <button id="about-btn">About</button>
      <h1>HOME</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-nav">
    <h1>Bottom Nav</h1>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```